# Having issues using the sort() method

Tags: python, sorting

The error:

```
File "C:\Users\mike\Desktop\tutorial2.py", line 62, in <module>
   ​usernames.sort()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort
```

My code:

```
usernames = []
usernames.append('doug')
usernames.append('sara')
usernames.append('carol')
for usernames in usernames:
    print("Hello, " + usernames.title() + "!")
usernames.sort()
for usernames in usernames:
    print("Hello, " + usernames.title() + "!")
```

I've just started learning Python a few days ago via [Introduction to Python](http://www.introtopython.org/). I imagine this is a very simple question to be asking on here, but this is the first thing I've run into that I can't seem to figure out.

I'm learning the basics of lists and am attempting to sort the one I've created. It worked once, but the error popped up when I tried to use `usernames.sort(reverse=True)` and could never get that to work. I deleted the code and typed it up again, but now I'm running into the problem again with just attempting usernames.sort. As far as I can tell I'm following the instructions correctly on the tutorial.

I'm using the [Geany IDE](https://www.geany.org/), if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing `usernames` from `list` to `str` in the `for` loop, change the variable to `username`

```
for username in usernames:
    print("Hello, " + username.title() + "!")
```

Comment: Thank you! You and the other person that replied gave me the same advice and it worked. And not only did it work, but I understand what I did wrong the first time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saying for usernames in usernames:

Try:

```
for user in usernames:
    print("Hello, " + user.title() + "!")

usernames.sort()

for user in usernames:
    print("Hello, " + user.title() + "!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using "usernames" for each object in your "usernames" list. The name of the iterator object should be different. You can use any reasonable and readable name for the iterator. For instance, "name", "username" or "user" are great options. The iteration would be like this:

```
for name in usernames:
    print(f"Hello {username.title()} !")
```

And by the way, instead of adding "+" to concatenate the strings and variable's values, you can use "f-string" which formats your print functions in a neat way like this:

```
print(f"anything here {your_defined_variables} anything here {another_varibale}.")
```

Happy Pythoning!